# Css animation not working nothing displayed in the browser

Tags: css, css-animations

```
.slider{
        width: 890px;
        height: 400px;
        background: url(1.png);
        margin: 100px auto;
        animation-name: slide;
        animation-duration: 10s;
        animation-delay: 0s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        animation-direction: normal;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        @keyframes slide{
            25%{
                background: url(2.png);
            }
            50%{
                background: url(3.jpg);
            }
            75%{
                background: url(4.png);
            }
            100%{
                background: url(1.png);
            }
```

above is the css of the a div box where i wanted to place a somewhat auto slideshow of images. Just read about css animations but when i tried to implement it nothing happens can someone please help me as for where I'm being wrong and can provide an easy example on the same concept which I'm trying would be a great help for me

Comment: you are missing a `}` before the keyframe definition (closing as typo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using exactly the same code as mentioned above, it has some mistakes.

1. You have defined the slide keyframes within the slider class properties, it must be standalone as it is not the part of slider class properties directly and it could be used with several other classes.

**Please find the corrected complete code below:**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Pure CSS Slider</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="author" content="https://akashshivanand.com">
  <style>
    .slider {
      width: 890px;
      height: 400px;
      background: url("http://lorempixel.com/890/400/sports");
      margin: 100px auto;
      animation-name: slide;
      animation-duration: 10s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
      animation-direction: normal;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @keyframes slide {
      25% {
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/890/400/sports/1);
      }
      50% {
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/890/400/sports/2);
      }
      75% {
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/890/400/sports/3);
      }
      100% {
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/890/400/sports/4);
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="slider"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the `animation-play-state` is not needed, it's by default running

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks for mentioning; if it's playing by default we can skip it. I mentioned this point as it was noticed that in some versions of a few browsers it isn't the case.

Comment: what kind of browsers? and what versions? It should be playing by default everywhere. If not, then it's a bug.